# GetAsyncKeyState VK_LBUTTON. Name does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(UInt16 virtualKeyCode); 

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON = 0x01))
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error saying "The name 'VK_LBUTTON' does not exist in the current context". Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use following code.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(UInt16 virtualKeyCode);
private const UInt16 VK_MBUTTON = 0x04;//middle mouse button
private const UInt16 VK_LBUTTON = 0x01;//left mouse button
private const UInt16 VK_RBUTTON = 0x02;//right mouse button
```

For more detail 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: I now have         [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(UInt16 virtualKeyCode);
        private const UInt16 VK_LBUTTON = 0x01;

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON))// this is the highlighted error
            {
                MessageBox.Show("test");
            }
        }
    }
}
 and it says "Cannot imlicitly convert type 'short' to 'bool'"

Comment: You can do like that                  if((bool)GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON))